# Unable to build WebRTC on iOS for arm64

Tags: objective-c, arm64, xcode12, webrtc-ios

I am trying to make a WebRTC.xcframework build for on an iOS device.

Here is what I am running to build it.

```
gn gen out/ios_arm64device --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64" ios_code_signing_identity="********" ios_code_signing_identity_description=""'

ninja -C out/ios_arm64device sdk:framework_objc

xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework out/is_arm64device/WebRTC.framework -output out/arm64/WebRTC.xcframework
```

However after I add the WebRTC.xcframework to my project I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCPeerConnectionFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RTIWebRTCClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCDefaultVideoDecoderFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RTIWebRTCClient.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RTCDefaultVideoEncoderFactory", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in RTIWebRTCClient.o
  "_RTCInitializeSSL", referenced from:
      -[RTIWebRTCClient configure] in RTIWebRTCClient.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Are you able to tell what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add the argument `rtc_enable_symbol_export=true` in your `gn gen` and generate your framework again, it should work.

```
gn gen out/ios_arm64device --args='target_os="ios" target_cpu="arm64" ios_code_signing_identity="********" ios_code_signing_identity_description="" rtc_enable_symbol_export=true'
```